# Hyperledger fabric 2.0 -chaincode as external service:Unknown chaincodeType: EXTERNAL

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode

I am trying to set up the chain code as an external service as is specified in the [official doc](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.0/cc_launcher.html)

First thing is to set up the `externalBuilder` variable

```
chaincode:
  externalBuilders:
  - name: my-golang-builder
    path: /builders/golang
```

In my peer configuration, I have added the following to override this

```
- CORE_CHAINCODE_EXTERNALBUILDERS_PATH=/var/hyperledger/builderpath
- CORE_CHAINCODE_EXTERNALBUILDERS_NAME=externalbuilder
```

But when I run the `peer install lifecycle` i am getting

```
docker build failed: platform builder failed: Failed to generate a Dockerfile: Unknown chaincodeType: EXTERNAL
```

Still, it tries to install as the old way seems like my external builder path is not detecting

Can anyone know the solution

**UPDATE**

peer.yaml

```
peer1.base.right:
    container_name: peer1.right.base
    extends:
      file: base.yaml
      service: peer-base
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer1.right.base
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1.right.base:9051
      - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:9051
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=peer1.right.base:9052
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:9052
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer1.right.base:10051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer1.right.base:9051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=RightOrgMSP
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/base.right/peers/peer1.base.right/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/base.right/peers/peer1.base.right/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
        - ./chaincode/external_builder:/builders/external
        - ./fabric-config:/etc/hyperledger/fabric
        - peer1.base.right:/var/hyperledger/production
    ports:
      - 9051:9051
    networks:
```

`- ./fabric-config:/etc/hyperledger/fabric` is the path of core.yaml

**core.yaml**

```
 ......
 externalBuilders:
              - name: external-builder
                path: /builders/external
                environmentWhitelist:
                   - GOPROXY
 ......
```

Comment: Was there any solution ?

Comment: Did you find out what the issue was? I'm having the same issue and could swear I have the configs and proper permissiosn set, it actually used to wor, then I recreated everythign from scatch and no longer works, not sure what I missed

Comment: @appbootup please see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue , i actually put the wrong path for the core.yaml file

The actual should look like this. Edit your docker file and modify the peer docker volume section according to this

```
 - ./config/core.yaml:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/core.yaml
```

Answer (score 2):

You cant override the chaincode.externalbuilders with environment properties. It is a complex object not a set of individual properties. Not all properties in core.yaml can be overriden with environment variables.

Comment: Meaning i need to add core.yaml file to my peer configurations

Comment: I have tried that as well but still the same error .i am using docker compose to setup the network

Comment: Can you edit your original post to include your compose file and core.yaml

Answer (score 0):

I had this exactly same issue and oh boy I had trouble to find the cause.

So, what ended up happening for me was that the external builder wasn't executed and then the peer tried to install the chaincode by the traditional way where it generates the Dockerfile and at that part of the execution it gives the error because "external" type is not one of the default platforms (java, golang, node).

Then I started testing stuff and eventually went through core.yaml line by line to try to figure out what could cause it to skip my external builder. For me the cause was that the `externalBuilders` definition in core.yaml was indented too much to right so it wasn't under `chaincode` definition anymore. And for that reason of course the peer was setup wrongly in a way that it didn't even try to use the external builder.

So, make sure your yaml files are formatted properly.